# Gnome Disk Image Mounter Permission Issues

Tags: iso, disk-image, gnome-disk-utility

I am trying to mount an ISO but am getting permission issues:

[image: Screenshot of problem]

I have tried running disk-image-mounter as root which works, but while in nautilus, under other locations I see the image but am unable to open and view it. It gives me a popup saying unauthorized to perform operation, so I open nautilus as root but the Image isn't anywhere to be seen. What should I do?